# Extra files showing up in searching that are not in classpath

Tags: java, ide, classpath, myeclipse

In MyEclipse, when I do a search there are duplicate files that show up in the search results.  One is in the classpath and the other is not.  Is there a way I can exclude the directory(ies) that are not in my src directory from showing up in my search results?

Cheers!

Comment: Dale, there are several ways to search in MyEclipse - there's the open resource dialog and the workspace wide search (that you get to from the Search menu). Can you tell us which you're using? Since you mention classpath, can you also mention the types of files you're search for? Are you looking for Java classes?

Comment: Correct.  I'm looking for just java classes and it is picking up java classes that are not on the classpath.

Comment: The best way to find Java classes on your classpath is to use Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + T (the Open Type action). If you use a simple file search (you didn't answer my question about what search you're using) it will find all files in the workspace and is Java agnostic. You can also consider using The Search > Java Search option to limit your results to Java entities on the classpath.

Comment: I think this is happening due to the structure of my project in Eclipse.  I have a main folder and then all of the projects in that.  Like  Project/Main Project/second Project/third so the files so up under both Project/Main and Main.